# How to refer to BaseUsers.class.php in action?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

If i will refer to UsersTable.class.php in action i use

```
Doctrine::getTable('Users')->getCity($test);
```

In BaseUsers.class.php i have:

```
@method Users setCity()     Sets the current record's "city" value
```

How can i refer to this file in action.class.php ?

by the way how can i refet to Users.class.php ?

thanks for help!

Comment: What do you mean by referring to? And what is your schema, what should UsersTable::getCity() be? We need some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

city is a property of one object.. with the table you will get a collection.

what you want is:

```
$users = UsersTable::getInstance()->findByCity('name');
```

or

```
$user = UsersTable::getInstance()->find(1); //get your first user
$user->setCity('Zurich'); // set the city-property of the first user to Zurich
$user->getCity(); // will return Zurich
```